# Building indigo on 14.10

Tags: ros, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to build indigo on Utopic.

I have to run Utopic due to several issues that were solved in 14.10.

I tried the build from source, but I get

gazebo_ros: No definition of [gazebo] for OS version [utopic]
gazebo_plugins: No definition of [gazebo] for OS version [utopic]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196076/building-indigo-on-14.10/) by [Fullmetal99012](https://answers.ros.org/users/20597/fullmetal99012/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2014-10-27

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are two files you need to create to set up local rosdep rules on your machine:

`/etc/ros/rosdep/local.yaml`, with the contents (note that the formatting and indentation in this file are important):

```
gazebo_ros:
    ubuntu: []
gazebo_plugins:
    ubuntu: []
```

And `/etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d/10-local.list` with the contents:

```
yaml file:///etc/ros/rosdep/local.yaml
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-10-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Fullmetal99012](https://answers.ros.org/users/20597/fullmetal99012/) on 2014-11-06**:
Thank you!!

**Comment by [oscillative](https://answers.ros.org/users/20785/oscillative/) on 2014-11-12**:
ahendrix- I too try to build from source on utopic and ran into the above error message on gazebo, e.g. "ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved to system dependencies: gazebo_ros: no def... gazebo_plugins..."  I tried your suggestion still the same error mesg

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-11-12**:
After you make these changes, you need to run `rosdep update`.

**Comment by [oscillative](https://answers.ros.org/users/20785/oscillative/) on 2014-11-13**:
OK, I tried "rosdep update", even after wiping and starting over with source build, but still unable to move pass the gazebo error..  I copied the pasted above into respective files you indicated, with root:root permission and readable by all.. I'm using utopic w/ ROS utopic (not trusty) repository?

**Comment by [Bidski](https://answers.ros.org/users/20952/bidski/) on 2014-11-27**:
I am also getting the OPs error. I just installed gazebo from source because I couldn't find any pre-built packages on Ubuntu Utopic.

I created the local.yaml and the 10-local.list files as you described and the error is still not resolved.

How to fix this?

**Comment by [georg l](https://answers.ros.org/users/22092/georg-l/) on 2015-04-06**:
Using that trick dependency checking passed. Unfortunately gazebo is still missing for compilation hence it fails. I couldn't find a clean way to install gazebo using ubuntu tools (apt dependencies broken) so it was necessary to take it directly from http://gazebosim.org/ . Version 5 seems to work.